# WordPress child theme enqueue_script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm having trouble adding a custom JavaScript file to my child WordPress theme. I'm use the Spacious WordPress theme, and created a Child theme based on it. I have successfully added a custom stylesheet, but so far been unsuccessful in adding a custom JavaScript file. I have followed the instructions provided in the WordPress Developers Handbook on [Including CSS & JavaScript](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/).

In my child theme **functions.php**

```
...
function spacious_child_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('custom_js',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom_js.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'spacious_child_enqueue_styles','spacious_child_enqueue_scripts','get_the_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_more');
...
```

What am I doing wrong? I can provide additional files and code if needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Her Jossua my mistake sorry. This one should work.

```
function spacious_child_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('custom_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/custom_js.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'spacious_child_enqueue_scripts' );
```

I was using `get_template_directory_uri();` which points to the parent theme directory.

Comment: I think I finally found what the issue was. It is related to the `add_action` code. I replaced mine with the one you provided and it worked. Here is the one I was using: `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'spacious_child_enqueue_styles','spacious_child_enqueue_scripts','get_the_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_more');` I'm not sure what is wrong with it

Comment: The last snippet I've posted should be working. If you have the js file in the child theme. Glad I helped! Please accept answer! Thanx

Answer (score 2):

@Herr Josua could you try this way?

```
function spacious_child_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('custom_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom_js.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'spacious_child_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: I tried not no luck. Currently in my `custom_js.js` file all I have is a simple `console.log('ready!');`. When I load the website I do not see any output in my console, nor do I see the file loaded in my sources tab (in both Chrome & Firefox), and I also do not see it within my DOM.

Comment: Like so i imagine: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 console.log('ready!'); });

Comment: Also do an inspect element and ' ctrl+f ' and put custom_js in the search field to see if it appears somewhere. The function is correct I've used it several times. Please also check if the file is located in the correct directory e.g. "child-theme/js"

Comment: Nope, still not displaying. The script is not being loaded. When I do a inspect element and search for the script it is not found.

Comment: Is the site live? Could you provide a link?

Comment: Unfortunately the site is not live.